# Editing small image in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to edit a small png image (4 x 8 pixels) in Gimp, but it's impossible to change some colors with `Bucket fill tool` or `color to alpha` for part of the image.

Do you know how to edit the image? Best would be `color to alpha`.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zoom and use a pencil with the selected color. You can draw with a one pixel point. You could also do quick toggle to work with the alpha and draw with the pencil in white/black.

Comment: Thank you, pencil works. Where can I find "quick toggle"?

Comment: Its in the lower left hand corner- it makes a red filter over the surface of the image and you can draw on it with black or white to make positive or negative alpha. It's super cool, I use it all the time. You can find it under Select> toggle quick mask.  Here's a link to the documentation. http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-channel-dialog.html#gimp-qmask Thanks for using Gimp!

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Colors->Hue and Saturation** to change colors
or you can colorize the whole image to one color with **Colors->Colorize**

Comment: it writes `Hue-Saturation operates only on RGB color layers`